# Delete item from BaseSwipeAdapter always removes last item

Tags: java, android, list, adapter

**EDIT: Solved by replacing the SwipeLayout class.**
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout/issues/17

If I remove an item from "rowItem" and call "notifyDataSetChanged();" it will always remove the last item. The positions and IDs are good because I get the proper modifications in database and logs.
Delete button is on the swiped view so I cannot edit the list outside the adapter.

How I can avoid this issue?

```
public class CalendarListArrayAdapter extends BaseSwipeAdapter {

private static final String TAG = CalendarListArrayAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
Context context;
List<Programare> rowItem;

CalendarListArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Programare> rowItem) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItem = rowItem;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItem.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return rowItem.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public int getSwipeLayoutResourceId(int i) {
    return R.id.swipe;
}

@Override
public View generateView(final int position, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.calendar_list_row, null);
    SwipeLayout swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout)v.findViewById(getSwipeLayoutResourceId(position));

    TextView txtServ = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.service);
    TextView txtDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);

    final Programare row_pos = rowItem.get(position);

    String[] dateTokens = row_pos.getDate().split(" ",-1);
    txtServ.setText(row_pos.getServ());
    txtDate.setText(dateTokens[1]);

    swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SimpleSwipeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {
            YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(500).delay(100).playOn(layout.findViewById(R.id.timeIcon));
        }
    });
    v.findViewById(R.id.delete).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /**
             * function to reschedule appointment
             * */
            // Tag used to cancel the request
            String tag_string_req = "req_reschedule";

            StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    Config.URL_RESCHEDULE, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Reschedule response: " + response);

                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                        // Check for error node in json
                        if (!error) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Reprogramat!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d("position", String.valueOf(position));
                            Log.d("row_pos", String.valueOf(row_pos));
                            Log.d("row_item to remove", row_pos.getObjId());

                            row_pos.setConfirm(3);
                            rowItem.remove(position);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            //rescheduleSMS(row_pos.getDate(),row_pos.getClientPhone());
                        } else {
                            // Error in login. Get the error message
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(context,
                                    errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // JSON error
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }
// code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you populate your list with data, the adapter loads all values to list along with ItemID's assigned to it. At the end the adapter holds the itemId of last item that was loaded in the list. so if you will perform any action it will be performed to last item. To overcome this, you need to set the deletion at the same place where you are loading the data to the list.You'll need to use view to getItemID(). This is how the adapter works. Now You'll have to make the edits.

Comment: I've managed to solve it. It was a issue from the swipe lib. https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout/issues/17   Thanks anyway!